# GitHub actions issue with .net framework nuget package

Tags: github-actions, xunit, cicd, .net-4.8

I have tried multiple things but can't get this to work. All I am trying to do is to build a .cproj file for a xunit project. This is the .csproj file,

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net481</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <Company>Beckman Coulter</Company>
    <AssemblyVersion>3.2.99.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>3.2.99.0</FileVersion>
    <Version>3.2.99.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Config\config.zip">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Castle.Core" Version="5.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.18.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="4.5.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" Version="4.5.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.abstractions" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.analyzers" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.Core.Interface">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\Labcyte.Core.Interface.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.Core.NLog">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\Core\CoreServer\Labcyte.Core.NLog.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.EchoNET.HostServices">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\Labcyte.EchoNET.HostServices.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.EchoNET.Interface">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\Labcyte.EchoNET.Interface.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.EchoNET.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>false</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\Labcyte.EchoNET.Data.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.EchoNET.Instrument, Version=0.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\Labcyte.EchoNET.Instrument.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj">
      <Project>{E458DB5E-F29F-43F5-8515-B9F456152CE3}</Project>
      <Name>Labcyte.Echo.Commands</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FluidTransferInterface\FluidTransferInterface.csproj">
      <Project>{1188c350-8068-4576-8d6d-b84c0ea2a936}</Project>
      <Name>FluidTransferInterface</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\HarrierFluidTransfer\HarrierFluidTransfer.csproj">
      <Project>{4DF52F46-535C-4144-A165-8D2D826394A9}</Project>
      <Name>HarrierFluidTransfer</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Data\InvalidSurveyData_384PP_AQ.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\SurveyData_384PP_AQ.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\WellProtocol_NoDestPlate_Result.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\WellProtocol_NoPlates_Result.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\PlateMapTestExample.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\PlateMapTestExample_Bad.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\PlateMapData_384PP_AQ.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\PrivateAndPublicExpectedEchoConfig.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\PrivateAndPublicExpectedMultiplePeripheralEchoConfig.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\PrivateAndPublicUserEchoConfig.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\PrivateAndPublicUserMultiplePeripheralEchoConfig.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\PublicExpectedEchoConfig.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\PublicExpectedMultiplePeripheralEchoConfig.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\PublicExpectedPeripheralEchoConfig.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\PublicUserEchoConfig.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\PublicUserMultiplePeripheralEchoConfig.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\PublicUserPeripheralEchoConfig.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\WellProtocol_NoPlates.xml">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\SurveyTestProtocol__Interleave_3rd__384PP_AQ_GP3.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\SurveyTestProtocol__Interleave_Decompress__384PP_AQ_GP3.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\SurveyTestProtocol__Quadrant_Decompress_4th__384PP_AQ_GP3.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\SurveyTestProtocol__Replicate__384PP_AQ.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
     <None Update="Data\TransferResultData.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Data\WellProtocol_NoDestPlate.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In this file, see the Labcyte.Echo.Commands, that's what is giving me the issue. Now I was building an other project called EchoServer (step 1 in my .yml file below). When I did that it built the Labcyte.Echo.Commands project also. When I say `ls ./Echo/Server/Labcyte.Echo.Commands/bin/Release`, I am able to see the MathNet.Numerics.dll in the folder (step 3 in my .yml).

Here are my GitHub actions .yml file,

```
- name: Build the EchoServer solution   #step 1
  run: msbuild ./Echo/EchoServer.sln /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release"

- name: Restore NuGet packages   #step 2
  run: nuget restore ./Pico/Medman/FluidTransferTests/FluidTransferTests.csproj

- name: List files in bin     #step 3
  run: ls ./Echo/Server/Labcyte.Echo.Commands/bin/Release

- name: Install MathNet Nuget package   #step 4
  run: nuget install MathNet.Numerics -Version 4.7.0 -DirectDownload -OutputDirectory ./Echo/Server/Labcyte.Echo.Commands/bin/Release

  
- name: Build the Fluid Transfer tests project   #step 5
  run: dotnet build ./Pico/Medman/FluidTransferTests/FluidTransferTests.csproj
```

Step 3 these are the files I see,

[image: files generated]

I tried Step 4 and it works fine, it manually installed MathNet.Numerics into the Release, it prints,

```
Run nuget install MathNet.Numerics -Version 4.7.0 -DirectDownload -OutputDirectory ./Echo/Server/Labcyte.Echo.Commands/bin/Release
Feeds used:
  C:\Users\runneradmin\.nuget\packages\
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\

    Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.7.0' with respect to project 'D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\bin\Release', targeting 'Any,Version=v0.0'
    Gathering dependency information took 539 ms
    Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.7.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
    Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
    Resolving actions to install package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.7.0'
    Resolved actions to install package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.7.0'
    Retrieving package 'MathNet.Numerics 4.7.0' from 'C:\Users\runneradmin\.nuget\packages\'.
    Adding package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.7.0' to folder 'D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\bin\Release'
    Added package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.7.0' to folder 'D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\bin\Release'
    Successfully installed 'MathNet.Numerics 4.7.0' to D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\bin\Release
    Executing nuget actions took 725 ms
```

Now for the Step 5 I am building the .csproj of the xunit project, I get this build error `The type or namespace name 'MathNet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]`.

```
Run dotnet build ./Pico/Medman/FluidTransferTests/FluidTransferTests.csproj
MSBuild version 17.7.3+8ec440e68 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Pico\Medman\FluidTransferTests\FluidTransferTests.csproj (in 318 ms).
  Restored D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj (in 316 ms).
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_PlateRegistration.cs(278,10): warning CS1030: #warning: 'ZSMITH - Inconsistently storing well row/column indicies as 0 and 1 based...' [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_PlateHandling.cs(3,10): warning CS1030: #warning: 'ZNSMITH REMOVE THIS!' [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_Wrapper.cs(23,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MathNet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_PlateClassification.cs(20,24): warning CS0108: 'EchoCommands.ClassifySourcePlate()' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.ClassifySourcePlate()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_Plates.cs(86,32): warning CS0108: 'EchoCommands.GetPlate(string)' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.GetPlate(string)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_SurveysTransfers.cs(259,33): warning CS0108: 'EchoCommands.DoSurveyFromCSV(string, double)' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.DoSurveyFromCSV(string, double)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_SurveysTransfers.cs(276,33): warning CS0114: 'EchoCommands.DoFlybySurveyFromCSV(string, double)' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.DoFlybySurveyFromCSV(string, double)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_Wrapper_IO.cs(72,21): warning CS0108: 'EchoCommands.OpenDoor()' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.OpenDoor()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_Wrapper_IO.cs(122,21): warning CS0108: 'EchoCommands.CloseDoor()' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.CloseDoor()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_Wrapper_IO.cs(595,21): warning CS0108: 'EchoCommands.EnableDeIonizer(bool)' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.EnableDeIonizer(bool)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]

Build FAILED.

D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_PlateRegistration.cs(278,10): warning CS1030: #warning: 'ZSMITH - Inconsistently storing well row/column indicies as 0 and 1 based...' [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_PlateHandling.cs(3,10): warning CS1030: #warning: 'ZNSMITH REMOVE THIS!' [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_PlateClassification.cs(20,24): warning CS0108: 'EchoCommands.ClassifySourcePlate()' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.ClassifySourcePlate()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_Plates.cs(86,32): warning CS0108: 'EchoCommands.GetPlate(string)' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.GetPlate(string)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_SurveysTransfers.cs(259,33): warning CS0108: 'EchoCommands.DoSurveyFromCSV(string, double)' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.DoSurveyFromCSV(string, double)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_SurveysTransfers.cs(276,33): warning CS0114: 'EchoCommands.DoFlybySurveyFromCSV(string, double)' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.DoFlybySurveyFromCSV(string, double)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_Wrapper_IO.cs(72,21): warning CS0108: 'EchoCommands.OpenDoor()' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.OpenDoor()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_Wrapper_IO.cs(122,21): warning CS0108: 'EchoCommands.CloseDoor()' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.CloseDoor()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_Wrapper_IO.cs(595,21): warning CS0108: 'EchoCommands.EnableDeIonizer(bool)' hides inherited member 'InstrumentController.EnableDeIonizer(bool)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\EchoCommands_Wrapper.cs(23,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MathNet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\Echo65XPlus\Echo65XPlus\Echo\Server\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj]
    9 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:16.22
```

Comment: Mixing `msbuild`, `nuget`, and `dotnet build` is a bad approach, as they target different scenarios and don't often work well together. Can you consolidate everything around just `msbuild` (used internally by VS)?

Comment: Sure when I use msbuild the problem is, it says I need to target a .sln file. If I try to build a .csproj file, it's failing and clearly says in the error, probably because you are building a .csproj file. But I'll try to create a sln file and try to build using msbuild

Comment: If you run `msbuild --help` to learn the command line arguments, you won't be surprise to find that `.csproj` is fully supported.

Comment: Thank you so much. That gives me an idea. Since I am building an xunit project, I want to try this https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.msbuild

Comment: I was able to install the package fine in a folder called third party. I am able to see the file. But when i run ./ThirdParty/xunit.runner.msbuild2.5.2  ./Pico/Medman/FluidTransferTests/FluidTransferTests.csproj  /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release"
it says "is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable
     program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
      again." Do you know how can I use this?